Reconfigure an existing SSAS Cube
How can I add new SQL table to an existing SSAS cube?
I’ve done an MDX query in SSMS to see the structure of the cube but I couldn't figure out how to add anything new. The existing SSAS cube has an older dataset within it but I wanted to update it.
